# How to reload data in a tableview without losing previous data (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, reloaddata

I have a tableview that will receive data on demand. however when I call the function scrollViewDidEndDragging that has a call to the tableview.reloadData () it replaces the data previously loaded.

```
func carregaDados(pagina : Int)
{
    let pg : String = String(pagina)
    liberaLoad = false
    var url : String = "my rest json"
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler: { (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
        let jsonResult : NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary
        if(jsonResult != nil){
            //process json
            let jsonUnico: NSMutableArray! = jsonResult["lista"] as? NSMutableArray
            self.tableList = jsonUnico
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.liberaLoad = true
        }else{
            //nao foi possivel ler o json
        }
    })

}
```

Here I have the function it was to give a append the data

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let currentOffset : CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    let maximumOffset : CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= -60.0 && liberaLoad) {
        self.carregaDados(2)
    }
}
```

my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustonImageTableViewCell
    let reeditList : NSMutableDictionary = self.tableList[indexPath.row] as NSMutableDictionary
    let tipo = reeditList["tipo"] as? String
    cell.lblTipo.text = tipo
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data that you want to save for your cells, you should consider saving it in your own modelObjectsForCells. When creating `UITableViewCells` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you will create cells according to the respective modelObjectForCells and you will need to modify the corresponding modelObject when data in some cell is changed.

This will make sure that your `UITableViewCell` retain data.

Comment: hello, I'm actually reading about it, but I could not run yet

Comment: @leedream awesome. After you are done reading and if you have any questions I would love to answer. :)